# How to access service through ingress from inside and outside server

Tags: kubernetes

Using nodePort service with ingress, I success expose the service to the out world.

```
--- service
NAMESPACE       NAME            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   
default         kubernetes      ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP
default         postgres        ClusterIP   10.106.182.170   <none>        5432/TCP
default         user-api        NodePort    10.99.12.136     <none>        3000:32099/TCP
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx   NodePort    10.110.104.0     <none>        80:31691/TCP,443:30593/TCP
--- ingress
NAME          HOSTS                ADDRESS        PORTS   AGE
app-ingress   example.com          10.110.104.0   80      3h27m
```

The rule of ingress show below.

```
  Host                Path  Backends
  ----                ----  --------
  example.com
                      /user-api   user-api:3000 (172.16.117.201:3000)
```

If my user-api have a restful api `/v1/health` interface, how to access this api inside and outside server?

Answer (score 2):

From the inside, http://user-api.default:3000/user-api. From the outside, use any node external IP (see `kubectl get node -o wide` for a list of them).

Comment: Could use the example.com from outside? How to config it?

Comment: You would have to use DNS to set up an A or CNAME record pointing your domain at one or more of your node IPs. It’s more common to use a LoadBalancer type service for your Ingres Controller because of this.

Comment: What's the common way to use LoadBalancer in any Cloud server?

Comment: Normally a cloud controller will have already been set up for you, so just change the Service type to LoadBalancer and it will give you the IP to set up in DNS under external-ip.

Comment: How to choice the version of nginx-ingress? Is it possible to choice the loadBalace nginx-ingree with the clusterIP service?

Comment: I don't understand, sorry. Edit the ingress-nginx Service to be type LoadBalancer and it will probably just do the setup for you.